# How to get data from mySQL database table with certain answer into php output

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I am a new guy when it comes to using php and mysql. I am just working on something for my personal development and I have ran into a few things that I can not find the answer to.

I have found from the the php.net tutorials on mysql and php output that I can use the following to fetch my data from the database (this is local wamp server and I know not to use Root and no password for my database)

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "mydatabase");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM `tblinvoices` ORDER BY `status` DESC";

if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $query)) {

    /* fetch associative array */
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        printf("%s (%s)\n <br>", $row["userid"] . "<br>", $row["status"], $row["duedate"]);
    }

    /* free result set */
    mysqli_free_result($result);
}

/* close connection */
mysqli_close($link);
```

Here is what columns I have in my database for reference.

```
+ ------------ + ------------ + ------------ +

| id            | date         | status     |

+ ------------ + ------------ + ------------ +

| 220852       | 2014-07-15   | unpaid
       |
| 220853       | 2014-07-15   | paid
       |
| 220856       | 2014-07-15   | unpaid
       |
| 220859       | 2014-07-15   | paid
```

I know I can use

```
 SELECT * FROM `invoices` where status = 'unpaid' ORDER BY `status` DESC
```

to display only the unpaid invoices but when it comes to outputting this into php I am having some issues with it.

But when I attempt to replace it with the mysql query above I do not get anything showing up at all. So my question is how can I display the userid, duedate of all of the unpaid invoices

Any help and guidance would be greatly appreciated!

-Joshua

Comment: Why order by status when you are only selecting records with a single status? This is s meaningless sort.

Comment: This was the way that phpmyadmin gave me the code and I used it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
printf ("%s (%s)\n <br>%s", $row["id"] . "<br>", $row["status"], $row["date"]);
```

**Edit:**

Change the query to get all unpaid records or in while loop check `$row['status'] = 'unpaid'`

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `tblinvoices` where status = 'unpaid' "
. " ORDER BY `status` DESC"; 

if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $query)) {

/* fetch associative array */
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    printf ("%s (%s)\n <br>%s", $row["id"] . "<br>", $row["status"], $row["date"]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that information, but it still shows all of the unpaid, paid and other statuses. I am looking to show only unpaid invoices. Any suggestions on that?

Comment: In loop check, if a variable $row['status] == unpaid

Comment: Thank you Tamil that has answered my question. Thanks once again. Have a great day.

Answer (score 0):

pass the table field value to the $row

```
 echo '<table><tr><td>User Id</td><td>Due Date</td></tr>';
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
       echo '<tr>'; 
       echo '<td>'.$row['id'].'</td>';   
       echo '<td>'.$row['date'].'</td>';   
       echo '</tr>';  
     );
    }
    echo '</table>';
```